# i have to error in using Dexter android library (1). cannot resolve withContext method. (2). cannot resolve permission Symbol

Tags: android

> My java file

```
package com.example.sunona;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;

import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dexter.withContext(this)  // cannot resolve withContext method.
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.Read_External_Storage) //cannot resolve permission Symbol
                .withListener()
                .check();
    }

}
```

> build gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sunona"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'
}
```

> Mainfest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sunona">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SunoNa">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried many things like using withActivity, capital small arrangements also. I visited many websites and many posts on StackOverflow. but I not found any satisfactory answer. finally, I am asking this question on StackOverflow. if anyone knows why this issue has? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the doc here is not updated: https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Because i was able achieve it with usage of `withActivity` instead of `withContext` because library does not contain that method.

Also make sure you have the right imports.

```
//manifest import should be this
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

// dexter imports
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dexter.withActivity(this)  // change this
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) //change this
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                    }
                })
                .check();
    }



}
```

Comment: but when i doing this i am getting another error: - cannot resolve permission Symbol

Comment: @SachinBurdak make sure you have right imports it should be `import android.Manifest;
`  but in your code posted you have `import java.util.jar.Manifest;` that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: thanks a lot, @Mayur gajra. this problem was occurring because of incorrect imports. problem solved.

Comment: i have a new error. error: non-static method continuePermissionRequest() cannot be referenced from a static context
                       PermissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                                      ^

Comment: @SachinBurdak I would suggest two things. 1) Read the library documentation and issues section carefully see if that solves problem 2) If the new problem arises ask a new question on StackOverflow and be specific to that issue only. Mention what new things you tried that led to the issue. So that future readers don't get confused. I hope you get my point.

Comment: may you provide link of the documentation page? because I can't find that page

Comment: They don't have a wiki yet but you can read homepage details here: https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter or you can checkout the sample app here: https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter/tree/master/sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231246/discussion-between-sachin-burdak-and-mayur-gajra).

Answer (score 0):

use this to get withContext() method
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'

Answer (score 0):

change the import to following:

```
   import android.Manifest;
```

and it works fine.